# Querying the Cache using Linq in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, caching

Search is the most used feature on our website and the search query is the most CPU intensive, complex and frequent query that executes on our db, causing heavy CPU usages on the db server. To reduce the load on the db we have been looking at various caching strategies. For now, we intend to use the ASP.NET Cache.

The idea is to have an in-memory db of the most frequently/recently created/accessed objects in the cache and then query the in-memory db using linq to come up with search results. My initial thought was to Cache a List of the Users and then query or modify this List using linq. But given the complexities of multiple threads accessing or trying to modify List I was looking at other options.

Which is when I thought that instead of Caching a List, cache the individual User objects with its Id as the key and try and query the Cache. At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx I see that the Cache has an extension method AsQueryable but I am not sure what does this mean. Cache is a key value pair so with AsQueryable will I able to query the keys and get a set of User Objects or will I able to query the User objects and get my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, cannot use AsQueryable to query User objects and get the desired result I was looking for.  So now I will be using a static List for the time being though I know I will have to change sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start this you really need to have some measurability in place around it -- there is no way to figure out if your changes help or hurt without having some good, solid data to make that judgement on. Performance, especially performance at scale isn't something you can think or guess through. You have to know your way through it.

As for your solution, I think you might well make the problem worse or at least create another problem here. Your database server is theoretically designed to handle arbitrary user queries across vast information sets efficiently. Linq is awesome but it is not really meant to be an ad-hoc search engine -- it doesn't have the sorts of indexing capabilities one really expects from search engines. Just because it can expose things as an IQueryable doesn't mean you should treat it that way. And even if you've got a way to efficently search the cache, you've got another problem to get past -- how do you identify what is most frequently used? And how do you manage the ASP.NET cache to not start ejecting things when it gets low on memory?

You would probably be better served here by:

- Starting with some good old fashioned database tuning -- why are your queries so slow and expensive? Are you missing an index somewhere?
- Looking at caching the results page output, especially if your search URLs are GET-able as that is pretty easy to manage. This is a great short term solution if the site is melting.
- Look at building the search bits properly. Using LIKE %whatever% is not a proper search. Full text indexes in your database is a good start. Something like [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is probably better.

Comment: It isn't a text search. In fact the search is basically a query, just that it has multiple joins and some user defined functions which make it slow. I think the Linq approach I was talking about is the correct approach, at least for now. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.